# List of links displaying in reverse order & not lined up in vertical center of UL

Tags: html, css, html-lists

My intent is the 'Print Pages' would be the first in the list. Also I can't get the text to be in the center of the UL vertically. Print pages is in the center but the other elements are too high.

[image]

HTML -

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#print_pages">
        <div id="checkoutbutton">
          <p>Print Pages</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
```

CSS -

```
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: white;
 }

#nav li {
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font: helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;

  }
#nav li a:hover {
  color: #f49131;
  background-color: #fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<li>`'s are reversed because you are using `float:right;`. Either use `float:left;` or reverse the order in the HTML.
To center the other elements, give them the same padding as the "Print Now" button.

Comment: I see. When I say `reversed` I mean I want the elements as they appear. So I could change the order in the HTML but I still want them on the RIGHT side of the screen...

Comment: Yes, then either reverse the html, or float the ul right, and have the li be display:inline-block;